# Find and Replace Using Vi and Regex

Tags: regex, vi

I have 12+GB sql file. It has been created using **--all-databases** option of MySQL.
I was able to open it in Vi via Cygwin in Windows.
This sql file contains multiple database blocks.
The common pattern repeating between the blocks is

```
--
-- Current Database: `database_name`
--
```

What I would like to do is to select all between

```
--
-- Current Database: `database_name`
--
```

and DELETE them.
How can I do that in Vi using Regex?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Try `:%s/--\s\+--\s\+Current Database: \`database_name\`\s\+--[^-]*\(-\(-\s\+--\s\+Current Database: \`database_name\`\s\+--\)\@![^-]*\)*--\s\+--\s\+Current Database: \`database_name\`\s\+--//g`.

Comment: Did it work? Or did you find your own way out?